# Regular expression find by key and extract value

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I try now for a while to extract values from a string.
but i don't get it to work. because of my bad regex knowhow.

this is my string.

```
/HAG5eHZ010C_EHZ1ZA22
0:0.0.0*255(1095100000053019)
1-0:1.8.1*255(000016.9862)
1-0:2.8.1*255(000001.5740)
1-0:96.5.5*255(80)
0-0:96.1.255*255(0000053019)
1-0:32.7.0*255(000.00*V)
1-0:52.7.0*255(000.00*V)
1-0:72.7.0*255(226.99*V)
1-0:31.7.0*255(000.00*A)
1-0:51.7.0*255(000.00*A)
1-0:71.7.0*255(000.22*A)
1-0:21.7.0*255(+00000*W)
1-0:41.7.0*255(+00000*W)
1-0:61.7.0*255(+00029*W)
1-0:96.50.0*0(89)
1-0:96.50.0*1(07CF)
1-0:96.50.0*2(18)
1-0:96.50.0*3(0E)
1-0:96.50.0*4(2D)
1-0:96.50.0*5(1A)
1-0:96.50.0*6(003D381B2609F5400803010700009F80)
1-0:96.50.0*7(00)
!
```

when I search for 0:0.0.0 i need 1095100000053019,
or when I search 1-0:61.7.0 i need +00029*W

btw: this an Smart Metering Message. coming out from an electricity meter IR interface.

many thanks for help.

Comment: The only way I know of doing exactly what you want is with lookbehinds which javascript's regex engine doesn't have. And what exactly do you mean by searching? You get what you search for. You can't search for one thing and get another, that's not how it works.

Comment: try this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZK03shJqBBRoh5CYlIJ1?p=preview) , search and you should get a list of all matches. Of course, I had to make some assumptions but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following regex pattern ([REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lQ1nN4/2)):

```js
var s = "\/HAG5eHZ010C_EHZ1ZA22\r\n0:0.0.0*255(1095100000053019)\r\n1-0:1.8.1*255(000016.9862)\r\n1-0:2.8.1*255(000001.5740)\r\n1-0:96.5.5*255(80)\r\n0-0:96.1.255*255(0000053019)\r\n1-0:32.7.0*255(000.00*V)\r\n1-0:52.7.0*255(000.00*V)\r\n1-0:72.7.0*255(226.99*V)\r\n1-0:31.7.0*255(000.00*A)\r\n1-0:51.7.0*255(000.00*A)\r\n1-0:71.7.0*255(000.22*A)\r\n1-0:21.7.0*255(+00000*W)\r\n1-0:41.7.0*255(+00000*W)\r\n1-0:61.7.0*255(+00029*W)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*0(89)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*1(07CF)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*2(18)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*3(0E)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*4(2D)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*5(1A)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*6(003D381B2609F5400803010700009F80)\r\n1-0:96.50.0*7(00)\r\n!";

var r = /([0-9-:.]+)\*(?:[0-9]+)\((.*)\)/g;
var m;

while ((m = r.exec(s))) {
  document.writeln('"' + m[1] + '"=>"' + m[2] + '"<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For 0:0.0.0: /^0:0\.0\.0[^(]*\(([^)]+)\)/
For 1-0:61.7.0: /^1-0:61\.7\.0[^(]*\(([^)]+)\)/
```

These are very similar - could build a pattern and change the pattern depending on which sensor reading you're after.

These regexes assume that what looks like newlines in your sample are indeed newlines